# Pandas read_csv ignore dollar sign when parsing numbers

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a csv file with some cells that have dollar signs (e.g. `$46.5`).  I am forcing all the types to be `numpy.float64` in the function `pandas.read_csv()`.  It complains about `ValueError: could not convert string to float: $46.5`.  Is there a way to handle this cleanly?

Comment: You'd have to strip and cast as a post-processing step or pass a method to `converters` param for `read_csv`

Comment: Are you trying to use floating point numbers for currency? You probably should be using `decimal`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Answer (score 13):

You can add a converter for the relevant column(s):

```
pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['$46.51', '$38.00', 40], 
              'col2': [1, 2, 3]}).to_csv('test_df.csv', index=False)

>>> pd.read_csv('test_df.csv', converters={'col1': lambda s: float(s.replace('$', ''))})
    col1  col2
0  46.51     1
1  38.00     2
2  40.00     3
```

Comment: You'll probably need to add the same logic for commas, or it will bomb trying to replace $1,437.22

Comment: @flyingmeatball use the `thousands=','` kwarg.